# Google plus insert activity on stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-api, google-plus, ruby-2.0, google-api-ruby-client

Tough time inserting an activity to google plus stream. After referring [google developers guide](https://developers.google.com/).
I found an example for java - https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

Is there a similar example to execute the `activites.insert` query using [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client).

**I followed following steps:**

Define access to app via [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)

```
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY      = google_config['KEY']
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET   = google_config['SECRET']
google_scope = "userinfo.email,
                userinfo.profile,
                plus.login,
                plus.me,
                plus.media.upload,
                plus.profiles.read,
                plus.stream.read,
                plus.stream.write,
                plus.circles.read,
                plus.circles.write"

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY, GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    {
        name: 'google',
      scope: google_scope,
      prompt: 'consent'
    }
end
```

Use the token and refresh token to execute api calls [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client). Am able to list the activities using "plus", but to insert an activity I should use plusDomains.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name =>'Demo GooglePlus',:application_version => '1.0.0')

plus = client.discovered_api('plus')

plusd = client.discovered_api('plusDomain')

client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load 

auth=client_secrets.to_authorization

auth.update_token!(access_token: 'aRandomToken', refresh_token: 'aRandomRefreshToken')

result = client.execute(:api_method => plus.activities.list,:parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'me'}, :authorization => auth)
>> This works, returns the list of activities
```

**Using plus Domain**

```
result = client.execute(:api_method => plusd.activities.insert,:parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'me'}, :authorization => auth)
>> Returns 403 Forbidden
```

Later I realized that google api requires domain wide delegaton to use the domains api(I think thats correct?)
https://developers.google.com/+/domains

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started#accessing_the_apis - Will the oauth used in Step 1 above would suffice ?

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python - Is there anything available in **RUBY**

I tried the service account setup also, created a business app and followed a [service_account example](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/blob/master/service_account/analytics.rb)

But still not luck.

Trying on terminal

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth ya12.AqwqwwAS1212grcECQ3iVAlg" -d "{'object':{'content':'Test message'},'access':{'items':[{'type' : 'domain'}],'domainRestricted':true}}" -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1domains/people/me/activities

Results in ->
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

May I get some help in inserting an activity on google plus user steam ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things to verify first:

1. You are using a Google Apps domain. This API does not work for regular Google+ users.
2. You enabled the **Google+ Domains API** in the Google APIs Console where you created your client ID. It is easy to miss the **Google+ Domains API** and accidentally enable the **Google+ API** instead.
3. Your Google App domain must have Google+ enabled by the Administrator.
4. The user that you are acting on behalf of either through the [standard OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/) or through [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation) has created a Google+ profile.

Next:
You cannot use the `plus.login` scope with the Domains API. I believe you also need to drop  the userinfo.* scopes. See the [full list of Google+ Domains API scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes).

Also, I believe your scopes are being defined incorrectly, I believe they need to use their full URIs:

```
google_scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read,
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write"
```

Comment: Thanks @BrettJ.
I eventually realized the scope errors. But I was actually trying to insert activity using a regular G+ account. I created an apps domain account here - http://www.google.com/a and it worked very well.
I suppose there's no way where I can write to regular G+ user's stream using the ruby-client for google api. Or there is ?

Comment: No, you cannot write to the stream for a normal Google+ account. We don't want the app spam that would result from that, but to the users in your own domain, do what you please.

Comment: @BrettJ There is an application called hootsuite, they are asking for offline access and they can post to the page directly, do they have anykind of partnership with google or something?

Comment: @BrettJ can you check this one, it will help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273766/google-moments-not-visible-on-users-feed-using-google-api-client-gem/28280992#28280992 thanks in advance