# Google + moments not visible on user's feed using google_api_client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus, google-api-client

I am trying to post to user's stream using google api client, I am using below mentioned code

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
client = Google::APIClient.new

   client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
   client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
   client.authorization.access_token = USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

plus = client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')

moment = {
    :type => 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
    :target => { :id => Time.now.to_i.to_s,
               :description => 'well this is it',
               :name => 'Well this is it'
    }
}

req_opts = { :api_method => plus.moments.insert,
             :parameters => { :collection => 'vault', :userId => 'me', },
             :body_object => moment
}

response = client.execute!(req_opts).body
```

After executing the above code I am getting the response as follow

```
    {"kind"=>"plus#moment",
 "type"=>"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
 "target"=>{"kind"=>"plus#itemScope", "id"=>"1422863753", "description"=>"well this is it", "name"=>"Well this is it"}}
```

But when I go to user's profile then I am not able to see this activity anywhere in profile.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** The moment methods do not write directly to a user's Google+ stream. They instead write to a user's profile, and are not necessarily viewable by others depending on the user's preferred sharing settings.

[Manage app activities in Google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/)

To find where moments are visible, view the profile about page and look for the "Apps with Google+ Sign-in" section.

[image]

Comment: I checked the settings, in my app the message that is coming up is "There are no activities to display. Learn more" and according to the settings, these posts should be visible to my circles

Comment: I am logged in as a user for which the moment is created and even I am not able to see the moments anywhere in the profile